# copy status list from CMD prompt into Excel spreadsheet

Tags: command-line

I ran a status int counters on my switches and want to copy this data into a spreadsheet. How can I do this to allow all columns to populate?

Comment: Pipe to a csv file via `>> file.csv` and ensure the values are comma separated.

Comment: Can you include a sample that shows the structure of the data that was output? is it comma separated? tab separated? Also, do you get the output on the command line, or does it go to a file? Oh, and approximately how much data are you looking at? [Edit]ing this information into your question will make it easier to give you better answers.

Answer (score 0):

First, follow the kindly suggestion from [Pimp Juice IT](https://superuser.com/users/510662/pimp-juice-it) above and capture the data by redirecting it to a file.

Once you have that file, open a blank document in Excel, click on the **Data** menu, and choose **From Text**. Find your file and read it in. Who knows, it might be close enough to what Excel can parse out to be useful as is. [The horse might learn to sing](https://everything2.com/title/And+maybe+the+horse+will+learn+how+to+sing).

If not, close Excel, and open the file with [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or a similar competent editor which can [transform newlines from Windows EOL to Unix EOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) or vice versa and which will show non-printing characters. Often, Notepad and Wordpad just won't get the job done because they don't recognize non-printing characters.

Determine the structure of the data, for you will need to convert it into a delimiter separated value file, like [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) or [TSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values).

Decide whether you will need to do this repeatedly, or if this is a one time task. If a one time task, use search-and-replace within the editor to transform the data into CSV or TSV. Then, open a blank document in Excel, click on the **Data** menu, and choose **From Text**. Find your file and read it in.

If you will need to do this repeatedly, determine if your favorite programming tools will do the substitutions easily. Many folks, use [grep, sed, and/or awk](https://blog.cee.moe/a-brief-introduction-to-grep-awk-and-sed.html) to transform data, but you can do it with a [Word Macro](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2952126/software-productivity/word-macros-three-examples-to-automate-your-documents.html) if you must. [Grep, sed, and awk](https://www-users.york.ac.uk/~mijp1/teaching/2nd_year_Comp_Lab/guides/grep_awk_sed.pdf) can be acquired and used freely for they are Open Source; the [Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) version is readily downloadable, and it's already included in the [MacOS bash shell](http://techslides.com/grep-awk-and-sed-in-bash-on-osx).

Comment: Although technically correct, this will be hard to execute by someone who is not an IT professional. Can't vote it up for that specific reason.

Comment: They're "running status int counters on my switches" which speaks to their level of expertise. How many folks managing multiple switches ain't IT pros?

Comment: It could happen in our company and it could have happened in companies where I worked previously. Basically an IT Pro manages the switches and provides the tools to lesser IT professionals. They then get asked to do something with it. They have some basic knowledge but not enough to have figured this out by themselves, otherwise they would not have asked the question in the first place. In my beginning years in IT, where I was mostly skilled from being born with computers, this could definitely have been a situation I would've been in. I would not have understood your answer.

Comment: Waal, heck fahr, I didn't know about the Holy Trinity of grep/sed/awk 'till I hadda do sumthin' like this. No challenge, no learning.

Comment: I didn't say your answer is wrong. I just missed a more hands-on approach which is why I didn't upvoted the answer. I felt it necessary to comment on this so you may learn from it. But its your answer still. :) No harm done.